# Image does not get resized when reading from database?

Tags: php, mysql, css

I am trying to read image stored in the MySQL database as BLOB type. It reads an displays the image fine but it would not resize the image i am using height width property but it would not work any reason why ?

My Goal is to resize the image because sometimes user upload image with large height an width.

```
      <?php

        $db=mysqli_connect("localhost",$user,$passwd,$dbname,$port);


        mysqli_select_db($db,"deal_bank");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM image";
        $sth = $db->query($sql);
        $result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);

        echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/ height=\"42\" width="\42\" >';

        ?

>
```

Comment: do not recommend you use  src=data, its not fully supported.

Comment: The code should perform thumbnail processing - *especially for data URIs, due to the increased bandwidth per request* - on the server. I would recommend doing this on upload, perhaps storing both the original and thumbnail. To see what (and why) the image on the client is the way it is, view the element with the *browser inspector tool*: view the attributes (HTML and CSS) and the computed size. (Also the SQL query is missing an adequate filter clause.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your escaping the double quotes when you dont need to.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'" height="42" width="42" >';
```

Comment: *sidenote* it is very bad practice to store your images in the database. You should store them in a folder and store the **path** to the image in the db.

Comment: Is it because of the processing speed or due to possibility of high bandwidth? Just trying to understand why its not a good practise ?

Comment: Both really, base64 increases the data length so your be sending more data about 37% more to the browser vs a std image, plus browsers wont cache the image so its sent on every request for it. Also will slow down the speed between your server and the mysql server. And yes it makes your database much larger and harder to import/export the normal fashion not to mention backing up or load balancing replication(perhaps), plus no support for IE6 and IE7. If you have a heavy site it will eventually become more of a problem then convenience. Upto you though :)